# SageMaker Studio: which AWS user profile am I using?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-experiments

After I login into a SageMaker Studio with a specific user profile, how can I find out which user profile I am logged in with? I know I can easily figure out which execution role I am using, but I wan to know which User Profile I am using. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read `/opt/ml/metadata/resource-metadata.json`.
`{"AppType":"KernelGateway","DomainId":"d-...","UserProfileName":"...","ResourceArn":"...","ResourceName":"...","AppImageVersion":""}`

Answer (score 0):

It is possibile using boto3 [describe_user_profile()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.describe_user_profile).

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

response = client.describe_user_profile(
    DomainId='string',  # The domain ID
    UserProfileName='string' # The user profile name. This value is not case sensitive
)
```

and this is the full response:

```json
{
    'DomainId': 'string',
    'UserProfileArn': 'string',
    'UserProfileName': 'string',
    'HomeEfsFileSystemUid': 'string',
    'Status': 'Deleting'|'Failed'|'InService'|'Pending'|'Updating'|'Update_Failed'|'Delete_Failed',
    'LastModifiedTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'CreationTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    'FailureReason': 'string',
    'SingleSignOnUserIdentifier': 'string',
    'SingleSignOnUserValue': 'string',
    'UserSettings': {
        'ExecutionRole': 'string',
        'SecurityGroups': [
            'string',
        ],
        'SharingSettings': {
            'NotebookOutputOption': 'Allowed'|'Disabled',
            'S3OutputPath': 'string',
            'S3KmsKeyId': 'string'
        },
        'JupyterServerAppSettings': {
            'DefaultResourceSpec': {
                'SageMakerImageArn': 'string',
                'SageMakerImageVersionArn': 'string',
                'InstanceType': 'system'|'ml.t3.micro'|'ml.t3.small'|'ml.t3.medium'|'ml.t3.large'|'ml.t3.xlarge'|'ml.t3.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.large'|'ml.m5.xlarge'|'ml.m5.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.4xlarge'|'ml.m5.8xlarge'|'ml.m5.12xlarge'|'ml.m5.16xlarge'|'ml.m5.24xlarge'|'ml.m5d.large'|'ml.m5d.xlarge'|'ml.m5d.2xlarge'|'ml.m5d.4xlarge'|'ml.m5d.8xlarge'|'ml.m5d.12xlarge'|'ml.m5d.16xlarge'|'ml.m5d.24xlarge'|'ml.c5.large'|'ml.c5.xlarge'|'ml.c5.2xlarge'|'ml.c5.4xlarge'|'ml.c5.9xlarge'|'ml.c5.12xlarge'|'ml.c5.18xlarge'|'ml.c5.24xlarge'|'ml.p3.2xlarge'|'ml.p3.8xlarge'|'ml.p3.16xlarge'|'ml.p3dn.24xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.2xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.4xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.8xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.12xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.large'|'ml.r5.xlarge'|'ml.r5.2xlarge'|'ml.r5.4xlarge'|'ml.r5.8xlarge'|'ml.r5.12xlarge'|'ml.r5.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.xlarge'|'ml.g5.2xlarge'|'ml.g5.4xlarge'|'ml.g5.8xlarge'|'ml.g5.16xlarge'|'ml.g5.12xlarge'|'ml.g5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.48xlarge',
                'LifecycleConfigArn': 'string'
            },
            'LifecycleConfigArns': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
        'KernelGatewayAppSettings': {
            'DefaultResourceSpec': {
                'SageMakerImageArn': 'string',
                'SageMakerImageVersionArn': 'string',
                'InstanceType': 'system'|'ml.t3.micro'|'ml.t3.small'|'ml.t3.medium'|'ml.t3.large'|'ml.t3.xlarge'|'ml.t3.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.large'|'ml.m5.xlarge'|'ml.m5.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.4xlarge'|'ml.m5.8xlarge'|'ml.m5.12xlarge'|'ml.m5.16xlarge'|'ml.m5.24xlarge'|'ml.m5d.large'|'ml.m5d.xlarge'|'ml.m5d.2xlarge'|'ml.m5d.4xlarge'|'ml.m5d.8xlarge'|'ml.m5d.12xlarge'|'ml.m5d.16xlarge'|'ml.m5d.24xlarge'|'ml.c5.large'|'ml.c5.xlarge'|'ml.c5.2xlarge'|'ml.c5.4xlarge'|'ml.c5.9xlarge'|'ml.c5.12xlarge'|'ml.c5.18xlarge'|'ml.c5.24xlarge'|'ml.p3.2xlarge'|'ml.p3.8xlarge'|'ml.p3.16xlarge'|'ml.p3dn.24xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.2xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.4xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.8xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.12xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.large'|'ml.r5.xlarge'|'ml.r5.2xlarge'|'ml.r5.4xlarge'|'ml.r5.8xlarge'|'ml.r5.12xlarge'|'ml.r5.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.xlarge'|'ml.g5.2xlarge'|'ml.g5.4xlarge'|'ml.g5.8xlarge'|'ml.g5.16xlarge'|'ml.g5.12xlarge'|'ml.g5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.48xlarge',
                'LifecycleConfigArn': 'string'
            },
            'CustomImages': [
                {
                    'ImageName': 'string',
                    'ImageVersionNumber': 123,
                    'AppImageConfigName': 'string'
                },
            ],
            'LifecycleConfigArns': [
                'string',
            ]
        },
        'TensorBoardAppSettings': {
            'DefaultResourceSpec': {
                'SageMakerImageArn': 'string',
                'SageMakerImageVersionArn': 'string',
                'InstanceType': 'system'|'ml.t3.micro'|'ml.t3.small'|'ml.t3.medium'|'ml.t3.large'|'ml.t3.xlarge'|'ml.t3.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.large'|'ml.m5.xlarge'|'ml.m5.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.4xlarge'|'ml.m5.8xlarge'|'ml.m5.12xlarge'|'ml.m5.16xlarge'|'ml.m5.24xlarge'|'ml.m5d.large'|'ml.m5d.xlarge'|'ml.m5d.2xlarge'|'ml.m5d.4xlarge'|'ml.m5d.8xlarge'|'ml.m5d.12xlarge'|'ml.m5d.16xlarge'|'ml.m5d.24xlarge'|'ml.c5.large'|'ml.c5.xlarge'|'ml.c5.2xlarge'|'ml.c5.4xlarge'|'ml.c5.9xlarge'|'ml.c5.12xlarge'|'ml.c5.18xlarge'|'ml.c5.24xlarge'|'ml.p3.2xlarge'|'ml.p3.8xlarge'|'ml.p3.16xlarge'|'ml.p3dn.24xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.2xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.4xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.8xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.12xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.large'|'ml.r5.xlarge'|'ml.r5.2xlarge'|'ml.r5.4xlarge'|'ml.r5.8xlarge'|'ml.r5.12xlarge'|'ml.r5.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.xlarge'|'ml.g5.2xlarge'|'ml.g5.4xlarge'|'ml.g5.8xlarge'|'ml.g5.16xlarge'|'ml.g5.12xlarge'|'ml.g5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.48xlarge',
                'LifecycleConfigArn': 'string'
            }
        },
        'RStudioServerProAppSettings': {
            'AccessStatus': 'ENABLED'|'DISABLED',
            'UserGroup': 'R_STUDIO_ADMIN'|'R_STUDIO_USER'
        },
        'RSessionAppSettings': {
            'DefaultResourceSpec': {
                'SageMakerImageArn': 'string',
                'SageMakerImageVersionArn': 'string',
                'InstanceType': 'system'|'ml.t3.micro'|'ml.t3.small'|'ml.t3.medium'|'ml.t3.large'|'ml.t3.xlarge'|'ml.t3.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.large'|'ml.m5.xlarge'|'ml.m5.2xlarge'|'ml.m5.4xlarge'|'ml.m5.8xlarge'|'ml.m5.12xlarge'|'ml.m5.16xlarge'|'ml.m5.24xlarge'|'ml.m5d.large'|'ml.m5d.xlarge'|'ml.m5d.2xlarge'|'ml.m5d.4xlarge'|'ml.m5d.8xlarge'|'ml.m5d.12xlarge'|'ml.m5d.16xlarge'|'ml.m5d.24xlarge'|'ml.c5.large'|'ml.c5.xlarge'|'ml.c5.2xlarge'|'ml.c5.4xlarge'|'ml.c5.9xlarge'|'ml.c5.12xlarge'|'ml.c5.18xlarge'|'ml.c5.24xlarge'|'ml.p3.2xlarge'|'ml.p3.8xlarge'|'ml.p3.16xlarge'|'ml.p3dn.24xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.2xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.4xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.8xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.12xlarge'|'ml.g4dn.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.large'|'ml.r5.xlarge'|'ml.r5.2xlarge'|'ml.r5.4xlarge'|'ml.r5.8xlarge'|'ml.r5.12xlarge'|'ml.r5.16xlarge'|'ml.r5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.xlarge'|'ml.g5.2xlarge'|'ml.g5.4xlarge'|'ml.g5.8xlarge'|'ml.g5.16xlarge'|'ml.g5.12xlarge'|'ml.g5.24xlarge'|'ml.g5.48xlarge',
                'LifecycleConfigArn': 'string'
            },
            'CustomImages': [
                {
                    'ImageName': 'string',
                    'ImageVersionNumber': 123,
                    'AppImageConfigName': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
        'CanvasAppSettings': {
            'TimeSeriesForecastingSettings': {
                'Status': 'ENABLED'|'DISABLED',
                'AmazonForecastRoleArn': 'string'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Top right-hand corner, to the right of the notification and profile icons. Whatever is between the profile icon and the `/` will match up to the user profile you logged in with.
[image]

And if you want to get more information about that user profile, you can go to File > New > Terminal, and type `aws sagemaker describe-user-profile --domain-id <domain-id> --user-profile-name <profile>`. The domain id is in your URL, between `https://` and `.studio.<region>.sagemaker.aws`.